# I'm in probation period and I cannot fit in with the company culture, how should I answer "why do you want to leave?" to my manager

Tags: probation, exit-interview

I'm in my current company, in probation period, for 2 weeks now, and I have the feeling that I just cannot fit in with the culture and environment.
The colleagues here are kinda aggressive (in work-related issues). They are unprofessional compared to my last company (non sense and not on point emails, no sense of responsibility nor reliability...). More importantly, work is poorly organized.
In the interview, my current manager did told me the job here is stressful, but I imagined it was stressful in a different way, not like this.
I kinda like my manager and I think he likes me. I know he had to do a lot during the recruitment process to get me the benefits I currently have. If I leave now, I'll put him in a really tough spot.
With that being said, it's still certain that I'm gonna leave.
Should I tell my manager the reasons, or should I say something comforting?

Comment: People usually advise someone in your situation to not burn any bridges and keep it cordial, but it's better in the long run for yourself to speak your mind.

Answer (score 3):

If you're leaving don't worry about your manager I doubt very much your 2 weeks has had all that much impact.

Exit interviews are for the benefit of the company, it's best to focus on where your career is heading then waste time griping or otherwise. In fact it can come back to haunt you in future. So my advice would be to use generic terms, .... better opportunities.... career advancement, stuff like that.

Comment: I think this is poor advice from a personal development perspective, but it seems to be the popular choice.

Comment: @mars - "poor advice from a personal development perspective" <- whatever do you mean? The OP is in a chaotic, and unprofessional environment. There's little benefit to sticking around, as identified by the person best suited to do so - the OP. There's nothing to be gained by being truthful about it, because I can assure you that the manager is well aware of the fact that the company is in shambles. Stating that as the reason you're quitting is a surefire way of making enemies, and not much else.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to express what you felt in the organisation and never ever attempt to maintain the comfort level of your manager.

What I understood from your statement is that there is no person-organization fit and you took a right call to leave the organisation and find a better one. it is wise decision and the best help what you can offer to the organisation is

> tell them the truth and they should not feel that they are doing right. This shall make them change before they hire the next guy

Comment: It may be dangerous to take this approach since he knows his manager for only two weeks. Maybe his manager is really cool and will take the positive criticism well, or he may burn bridges with him/other managers.